# TYPO3 : stdWrap.editIcons in CONTENT for non-admin BE_USER?

Tags: typo3

i make a quick typo3 6.2 extension with the extension builder (i'm a FE integrator) and i display content of tables in FE with Typoscript like this :

```
10 =  CONTENT
10 {
    table = tx_ensgue_domain_model_ue
    select {
    pidInList = 41
    selectFields = tx_ensgue_domain_model_ue.uid,tx_ensgue_domain_model_ue.syl_code,tx_ensgue_domain_model_ue.syl_titre
    join = tx_ensgue_ue_sylperiode_mm ON (tx_ensgue_ue_sylperiode_mm.uid_local = tx_ensgue_domain_model_ue.uid)
    where = (tx_ensgue_domain_model_ue.syl_titre LIKE '%%' AND tx_ensgue_domain_model_ue.deleted=0)
    andWhere = tx_ensgue_ue_sylperiode_mm.uid_foreign=1
    orderBy = tx_ensgue_domain_model_ue.syl_code
    }

    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {

    20 = TEXT
    20 {
            field = syl_code
            noTrimWrap=|[|] |
    }
    30 = TEXT
    30 {
            field = syl_titre
    stdWrap.editIcons = tx_ensgue_domain_model_ue:syl_code,syl_titre,syl_periode,syl_responsables
    stdWrap.editIcons.beforeLastTag = 1
    stdWrap.editIcons.iconTitle = Modifier l'UE
    required = 1
}
    wrap = <li > |</li >
    }

    stdWrap {
        wrap = <h2>Semestre 5</h2><ul class="syl_fe">|</ul>
        required = 1
    }
}
```

I try to use feedit (from the core) but the editIcons are only availables for Admin BE Users. A Non-Admin can edit a tt_content in a page, but it won't work if i display a list of tt_content within a CONTENT object.
It may be hard coded in typo3/sysext/core/Classes/FrontendEditing/FrontendEditingController.php (line 459 ?) but it's beyond my knowledge.
How can i use stdWrap.editIcons to allow non-admin be-users edit my tables ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching in `core/Classes/FrontendEditing/FrontendEditingController.php`.
In the function `allowedToEdit()`, it was working when `$mayEdit = TRUE;` or `$editAccessInternals = TRUE;` or `$checkEditAccessInternals = FALSE;`

My problem was in `core/Classes/Authentication/BackendUserAuthentication.php` (the Checking languages part).
It was checking for `$GLOBALS['TCA'][$table]['ctrl']['languageField']`.

So i replaced

```
$TCA['tx_ensgue_domain_model_ue']['ctrl']['languageField'] = 'sys_language_uid';
```

to

```
$TCA['tx_ensgue_domain_model_ue']['ctrl']['languageField'] = 0;
```

in my extension, and it's now working.

I don't really understand the change because my demo user had all rights over languages, and `config.sys_language_uid = 0` in my SETUP TS...